# How to download nycflights 13 package?

Tags: r, installation, view, download, load

I am failing to download the nycflight13 package.

I tried to download and install  nycflights13 package. A big file with nycflights13 has been downloaded in my computer, however I am still failing to get what I want.

Comment: Hello Founemakan. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: add what is error message you see and what command you used to  download the package, also add what is your r version and operating system

Answer (score 1):

To install the `nycflights13` package in R, use `install.packages()`.

We'll install the package, load it, and print a few rows from a couple of the data frames in the package. First, within R or RStudio, run the `install.packages()` function to install the package.

```
install.packages("nycflights13")
```

The result should look like this:

```
> install.packages("nycflights13")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/nycflights13_1.0.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4502401 bytes (4.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.3 MB
```

Next, to use the package, load the package into memory with the `library()` function.

```
library(nycflights13)
```

At this point we can access the data frames that are included in the package. For example, we'l print the first few rows of the `airlines` and `airports` data frames.

```
head(airlines)
head(airports)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(airlines)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  carrier name                    
  <chr>   <chr>                   
1 9E      Endeavor Air Inc.       
2 AA      American Airlines Inc.  
3 AS      Alaska Airlines Inc.    
4 B6      JetBlue Airways         
5 DL      Delta Air Lines Inc.    
6 EV      ExpressJet Airlines Inc.
> head(airports)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  faa   name                             lat   lon   alt    tz dst   tzone           
  <chr> <chr>                          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>           
1 04G   Lansdowne Airport               41.1 -80.6  1044    -5 A     America/New_York
2 06A   Moton Field Municipal Airport   32.5 -85.7   264    -6 A     America/Chicago 
3 06C   Schaumburg Regional             42.0 -88.1   801    -6 A     America/Chicago 
4 06N   Randall Airport                 41.4 -74.4   523    -5 A     America/New_York
5 09J   Jekyll Island Airport           31.1 -81.4    11    -5 A     America/New_York
6 0A9   Elizabethton Municipal Airport  36.4 -82.2  1593    -5 A     America/New_York
>
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to use nycflights13 you have to download the file first from CRAN site
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nycflights13/index.html

Then extract data inside the folder that keeps the downloaded binary packages, in my case is in this directory
C:\Users\Lilia\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMzik3E\downloaded_packages

And finally you can install the package using the command
install.packages(nycflights13)

Comment: It is not recommended to install packages this way.  You should really use the `install.packages` function as explained above.

Comment: I tried it, but for some reason it didn't work that's why I had to do it "manually"